# How to Filter my objects base in a property ? React JS

Tags: reactjs, object, filter

For example,

I have an array of objects which are movies with multiple genres and I just wanna render the ones with the horror genre for example. I already have one object filtered which is the one I took the information to render to the component, but I Have another component below that is a row of the movies, and I want the object movies to match the actual object genre. Like in Netflix "you might also like"  and pass that as a Prop and render only the movie pictures in the other component.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import movies from '../data/dataAll'
import SubRow from "./SubRow";

import './MovieDetails.css'

const MovieDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();

    // Get the Object info using id
    const movie = movies.find(movie => movie.id === parseInt(id))


    return (
        <div className=" bg-wrapper moviedetails">
            <div className="moviedetails-content bg-wrapper-content">
                <div className="moviedetails-content-info ">
                    <h2 className="movie-title">{movie.title}</h2>

                    <div className="movie-tags">
                    <span>{movie.rating}</span>
                    <span>{movie.type}</span>
                    <span>{movie.duration}</span>
                    </div>

                    <p className="movie-base">{movie.sinopsis}</p>
                    <hr className="line"/>
                    <p><strong>Genrer: </strong>{movie.genrer}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="banner-background bg-wrapper-image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${movie.cover})` }} >

            </div>

            <SubRow recomended={ }></SubRow>

        </div>
    );
}

export default MovieDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

const movies = [
  { title: 'Movie 1', genre: 'horror' },
  { title: 'Movie 2', genre: 'drama' },
  { title: 'Movie 3', genre: 'horror' },
  { title: 'Movie 4', genre: 'action' },
];

const HorrorMovies = () => {
  const horrorMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.genre === 'horror');

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Horror Movies</h2>
      <ul>
        {horrorMovies.map(movie => (
          <li key={movie.title}>{movie.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HorrorMovies;
```

To filter an array of objects based on a property value in ReactJS, you can use the filter() method. Here's an example of how you can filter an array of movies based on a specific genre:

```
import React from 'react';
import HorrorMovies from './HorrorMovies';
import MovieRow from './MovieRow';

const App = () => {
  const horrorMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.genre === 'horror');

  return (
    <div>
      <HorrorMovies />
      <MovieRow movies={horrorMovies} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default App;

```
import React from 'react';

const MovieRow = ({ movies }) => (
  <div>
    {movies.map(movie => (
      <img key={movie.title} src={movie.posterUrl} alt={movie.title} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default MovieRow
```

;

Comment: Thanks !, how can I do if I only want to render the ones with the same genre ? . Sorry I am new in this

Comment: The things is that I want  to render the genre but they are strings like "action,adventure" and I do not know how to render the ones that matches at least one, or should I just make the object with only one genre?